# How to obain current user when use Client Credentials Authorize Mode IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, abp

I practise the identity server4 samples follow by tutorial. 
There is doubt in chapter **Protecting an API using Client Credentials**

When athorized by client credentials. The demo will print the claims' {type , value  }

But who is the current user?

Under this authorize mode is for that api don't need user?
Perhpas there is something I don't know.

I'm leaning Identity server4 at first.

```
[Route("identity")]
[Authorize()]
public class IdentityController: AbpController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        // Who is the authorized user?
        return new JsonResult(this.CurrentUser);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using JWT? @Echo

Comment: The client credentials flow is the only flow that actually has no user. That's why the sub claim is missing. You sign in with the client credentials, not the user credentials. You can use this flow when there is no user involved, e.g. automated synchronization processes. For other types of access, e.g. website looking up information, the user logs in to the website (using another flow, like the hybrid flow), an access token is acquired (now containing user's sub claim), which can be used to access the api on behalf of the user.

Comment: @YigitTanriverdi  Actually I don't make clear the relation between identity, jwt, oauth and openId. Now I special one of authorization mode.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg According your meaning. Client credentials is just for the scenario that don't need fix user. It is used for common apis. e.g. background jobs, Rank list?  Am I catch your point?

Comment: Yes, the client credentials are typically used for machine to machine communication.